# Auto resize tabular row height

Tags: tables, spacing

After running following code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Schedulers} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{3cm}{Row 1. long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text } & RR & Round Robin \\
& EF & Earliest First \\
& LL & Lightest Loaded \\ \hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Row 2.} & MM & Min-Min \\ 
& MX & Max-Min \\
& DL & Dynamic Level \\ 
& RC & Relative Cost \\ \hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Row 3.} & PN & This paper \\
& ZO & Genetic Algorithm\\
& TA & Tabu search\\
& SA & Simlulated Annealing \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get this output:

[image]

What should I do to make first three rows (RR, EF and LL) accordingly higher?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `multirow` doesn't expand rows if it is bigger than the rows it is spanning. 
In this case changing `\\` to `\\[1cm]` make a reasonable result. A more automatic solution is possible but harder.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Schedulers} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{3cm}{Row 1. long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text } & RR & Round Robin \\[1cm]
& EF & Earliest First \\[1cm]
& LL & Lightest Loaded \\[1cm] \hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Row 2.} & MM & Min-Min \\ 
& MX & Max-Min \\
& DL & Dynamic Level \\ 
& RC & Relative Cost \\ \hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Row 3.} & PN & This paper \\
& ZO & Genetic Algorithm\\
& TA & Tabu search\\
& SA & Simlulated Annealing \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll be glad to know this auto solution. I need it, cause this table is only an example. I'm searching for solution that will work with variable amount of rows.

Comment: ...and with variable text in left cell