# Automatically adjusting multirow height in tabular

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create a table which contains (multiple) multirow cells with a certain width, automatically wrapping the text. However, when the text is too long, it spills over to the next cell.

I know I can use the `\\[1cm]` to manually solve this problem (also see [Auto resize tabular row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98955/auto-resize-tabular-row-height)) but I want to do this automatically. Is this possible?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|c}
     A & B  \\\hline
     \multirow{2}{4cm}{My long text here is ok, not long enough to spill} & 1 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 2 \\\hline
     \multirow{2}{4cm}{Other text here} & 3 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|c}
     A & B  \\\hline
     \multirow{2}{4cm}{My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this?} & 1 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 2 \\\hline
     \multirow{2}{4cm}{Other text here} & 3 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: MWE output]

I will accept answers using other environments/packages.

Comment: You could use the nested tabular approach instead of `\multirow`.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. Does this mean that the text will not be automatically wrapped into newlines?

Comment: The text in the left column will keep its automatic line breaks. See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

With multirow and a manually addd empty line: 


\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|c}
     A & B  \\\hline
     \multirow{2}{=}{My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this?} & 1 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 2 \\ 
      \\ \hline
     \multirow{2}{=}{Other text here} & 3 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

With nested tabulars:

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|@{}c@{}}
     A & B  \\
     \hline
     My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this? 
       & \begin{tabular}[t]{c} 1 \\ \hline 2 \end{tabular} \\ 
     \hline
     Other text here & \begin{tabular}[t]{c} 3 \\ \hline 4 \end{tabular} \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

---

For vertically centerd cells you could use the `cellspace` package. IIf the lenght of the text in the first column or the number of row in the second column changes, the value of `\cellspacetoplimit` has to be adjusted accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{array}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace} \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.5\baselineskip} \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit} \begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}|@{}c@{}}
     A & B  \\
     \hline
     My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this? 
       & \begin{tabular}{0c} 1 \\ \hline 2 \end{tabular} \\ 
     \hline
     Other text here & \begin{tabular}{c} 3 \\ \hline 4 \end{tabular} \\
      \hline \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good but creates a small issue. Is it possible to vertically center the first table like the second one? I.e. the divider between 1 and 2 should be in the middle of the cell.

Comment: Like so? https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvmNb.png Or do you alsso want to vertically center "1"  and "2"  in their respective cells?

Comment: Yes, ideally 1 & 2 should be aligned in their cells.

Comment: @orestisf: I am unfortunately not sure if this is achievable in an automatic way. If have however edited my anser to include a somewhat semi-manual way.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my table using your original answer and I am pretty happy with it, so I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (not really automatic) hack?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}|c}
     A & B \\\hline
    My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this? & \makecell{1 \\[0.5ex] \cmidrule(l{-7pt}r{-7pt}){1-1} 2}\\\hline
     \multirow{2}{=}{Other text here} & 3 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really need it to be automatic. The final table is big and is going to be generated by a script. If I could somehow infer & incorporate these numbers into my script (instead of manually adjusting them each time), this could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}


\SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{p{4cm}|c}
     A & B  \\\hline
     \SetCell[r=2]{} My super long text here will spill over to the next line. How do I avoid this? & 1 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 2 \\\hline
     \SetCell[r=2]{} Other text here & 3 \\\cline{2-2}
      & 4 \\\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]